# Android PhoneGap www folder in sdcard

Tags: android, cordova, web, sd-card

Is there a way to have the ww folder or most of the html, js, css files living in the sdcard and PhoneGap still loads them?

Comment: I don't see why not. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: I have tried but as I expected the files in the sdcard are out of scoope, thats because the www folder is treated like the root, there are ways to make calls for other files with javascript and ajax, but thats not what I need.

Comment: Yeah, if you were going to put the files on the SD card you may need to refer to them using absolute paths file:///sdcard/some/path/file.html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i've just tried loading css from sdcard, and it works. Just add

```
<link href="file:///sdcard/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in index.html, the apk will load css from sdcard.

but we must clear cache every program start. to do that, simply just add

```
super.clearCache();
```

before

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

in your .java in src folder.

Comment: I know it's been over 2 years since you wrote your answer, but could, explain more about the necessity of clearing cache? Will clearing cache affect local storage of the app?